# Android 6.0 Emulator process doesn't work

Tags: java, android, linux

I run Android-6.0.0_r41 version on emulator, and the linux kernel is android-goldfish-3.4. In my app, I need to read files in /system, /proc, /sys, etc, and I know I cannot read using java IO, so I try to read these files using runtime.getRuntime().exec() method.

I have rooted the emulator, and disabled selinux (setenforce 0). But I still cannot read these files. For examples, I want to read `/sys/kernel/security/ima/ascii_runtime_measurments` by cat command. I can read this file in adb shell, but I cannot read using exec() method. Following is code I used to read this file. The `str` is `NULL`, and I have tried sleep, process.waitfor() methods, and all failed.

Is this problem caused by Android 6.0? If I choose Android 5.0, can I read files except /data ?

```
 private String checkexist() {
        Process process;
        String val = "";
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
            process.getErrorStream();
            InputStream input = process.getInputStream();
            os.write(("cat /sys/kernel/security/ima/ascii_runtime_measurments\n").getBytes());
            os.write("exit\n".getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            while (true) {
                String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (str == null)
                    break;
                val = str;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "exist\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the error stream?

Comment: Hi, thanks @GenoChen From the errorstream I get that the su is not allowed. I need to modify the soucecode of su.c.

Comment: Have you forget to grant permission to your app?

Comment: I find what causes the problem. The native source code of android su.c don't allow other apps to access it. I modify the su.c by deleting "if (current_uid != AID_ROOT && current_uid != AID_SHELL) error(1, 0, "not allowed");", then the linux command can exec in the process.

Comment: Fake root lol. Then you recompile a `su` and replace the original may solve this problem.